# One rails db table stopped working, all others fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating a Rails "Movie Events" app. The database several tables with has_many, through: relationships.

The first tables created were for:
Events and Venues connected through an EventsVenues table.

I then created the relationships in the models, and then opened the rails console to populated the tables with test data and checked the relationships. Everything was working just fine and dandy.

I then went on to add additional tables with various relationships, populating them with test data, and checking those tables in turn. And all seemed to check out.

Finally I went back to re-test the Event table and got the following error message:

```
irb(main):013:0> Event
NameError: undefined local variable or method ` ' for main:Object
from /Users/Timo/Projects/openscreen_new/openscreen_db/app/models/event.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
from (irb):13
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/Timo/Projects/openscreen_new/openscreen_db/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/Timo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'irb(main):014:0>
```

All other tables work fine:

```
irb(main):015:0> Venue.first
Venue Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "venues".* FROM "venues"  ORDER BY "venues"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Venue id: 1, name: "Tim's place", description: "A darn stylish abode", street_number: 1, address_01: "rue des Pommieres", address_02: nil, country: "Luxembourg G.D.", google_map: nil, created_at: "2016-12-20 14:05:06", updated_at: "2016-12-20 14:05:06">
irb(main):016:0>
```

And:

```
irb(main):024:0> Venue.first.event_venues
Venue Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "venues".* FROM "venues"  ORDER BY "venues"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
EventVenue Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "event_venues".* FROM "event_venues" WHERE "event_venues"."venue_id" = $1  [["venue_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<EventVenue id: 2, event_id: 1, venue_id: 1, created_at: "2016-12-20 14:21:50", updated_at: "2016-12-20 14:21:50">]>
irb(main):025:0>
```

I don't recall changing anything in the Event model. It suddenly just started giving me error messages.

Any idea of what I am missing?

Comment: `NameError: undefined local variable or method  ' for main:Object`  - check 10th line of your `Event` model at `app/models/event.rb:10:in`

Comment: That solved it.

Comment: I had a non-breaking space on line 10.

Answer (score 0):

As the log suggests, you have an error :

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method ` ' for main:Object
```

You have an undefined variable at 10th line of `Event` model.